# Can I give each row an ID in a displaytag table?

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I can write a [decorator](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_decorators.html) to create the cells in the rows of a table. So it's easy to give `<td>` elements an `id` attribute, but can I give the `<tr>` an `id` attribute (using the decorator or anything else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can implement the `addRowId()` method in my decorator.
I should have spent longer reading the documentation.
http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-rowclass.jsp